# How export only row visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want export only row visible after filted but get all rows

this repo: https://github.com/FuriosoJack/TableHTMLExport

I use in my code :

> ```
> $('#export3').click(function(){
>     $("#table3").tableHTMLExport(
>         {   type: 'csv',
>             ignoreColumns:'.ignore',
>             ignoreRows:'.ignore',
>             filename: 'tebela_detalhes_erros_transf.csv',
>         }
>     );
> });
> ```

i think it will  edit in lib and add clouse for create class for use in ignoreColumns and ignoreRows

this code in jsfiffle https://jsfiddle.net/tiagopimentta/hx0vbL4p/14/

help guys please...

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you require you can dynamically add the `.ignore` class to the hidden rows. That way the exporter will ignore them:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/FuriosoJack/TableHTMLExport/v2.0.0/src/tableHTMLExport.js"></script>
<div class="modo-box">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Buscar..." autocomplete="off">
    <p id="emptyMsg2" style="display:none;">Nenhum registro encontrado.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-body box-fix">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped pt-5" id="table3">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="ignore">#</th>
          <th>Marketplace</th>
          <th>Erro</th>
          <th>Total</th>
          <th>Representa</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="bodyResult">
        <tr style="">
          <td class="ignore">1</td>
          <td>aaa</td>
          <td>Categoria não vinculada ao Mercado Livre 1262</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>30.77%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="">
          <td class="ignore">2</td>
          <td>bbb</td>
          <td>Categoria não vinculada ao Mercado Livre 1019</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.69%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="ignore">3</td>
          <td>ccc</td>
          <td>Categoria não vinculada ao Mercado Livre 636</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.69%</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="row container-fluid pt-4">
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="export3">
      <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Exportar Dados </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(".bodyResult tr")
    .show().removeClass('ignore')
    .filter((i, tr) => !$(tr).text().toLowerCase().includes(value)).hide().addClass('ignore');
  $("#emptyMsg2").toggle($(".bodyResult tr:visible").length === 0);
});

$('#export3').click(function() {
  $("#table3").tableHTMLExport({
    type: 'csv',
    ignoreColumns: '.ignore',
    ignoreRows: '.ignore',
    filename: 'tebela_detalhes_erros_transf.csv'
  });
});
```

Working example in [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/p7tb04du/1/) as SO snippets are sandboxed and do not allow dynamic file downloading.